# Email Content - Value without key

Tags: email

I am trying to read the content of the file inside the bucket of Amazon S3, I get this:

```
    Return-Path: <0100015e98afd4e4-7a7cffab-aeec-4ed9-968b-ed735a26d893-000000@amazonses.com>
Received: from a8-18.smtp-out.amazonses.com (a8-18.smtp-out.amazonses.com [54.240.8.18])
 by inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com with SMTP id vbghk0svnudf28mgos338lcri9ph21unj42pfa81
 for lists.center@laravel.paralejas.com;
 Tue, 19 Sep 2017 07:47:41 +0000 (UTC)
X-SES-Spam-Verdict: PASS
X-SES-Virus-Verdict: PASS
Received-SPF: pass (spfCheck: domain of amazonses.com designates 54.240.8.18 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.240.8.18; envelope-from=0100015e98afd4e4-7a7cffab-aeec-4ed9-968b-ed735a26d893-000000@amazonses.com; helo=a8-18.smtp-out.amazonses.com;
Authentication-Results: amazonses.com;
 spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of amazonses.com designates 54.240.8.18 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.240.8.18; envelope-from=0100015e98afd4e4-7a7cffab-aeec-4ed9-968b-ed735a26d893-000000@amazonses.com; helo=a8-18.smtp-out.amazonses.com;
 dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com;
X-SES-RECEIPT: AEFBQUFBQUFBQUFGdUFWcWNhK2RacFVsWHR6cU80UzJUWXFUOHQzZXFsTzlmVUIzMm5tQWkyS1I5STE4b0ZZTnRkY1RpS0tLdWtxRGE5RDRtcUtEemdoV285S1BPbDZETUxzNVpLMHFWcDdTWEh5U3hWSHQzM2p0UEhDY2J5OG5xcndieG5meTBrdkRBUllrd0NFRjZETExBOWszU1NJNmVhcHJQSWVRRVZ0dTQ5dWZZakVaMnJISUhEMStCeFVXWjRwTExWQlgrSkdpenY3Nm95Z01GbS9wNCs1Vy9IT2hqR2V0YjlteUpvZGZKWDVYQ09Xbi9qS1diUElqbm1mMFJDM1EyeWI4KzBFeUdXSXI1Nk1SMHpLamtVcWN6KzZWS3JsUkJ4NHA5RWhlTk5mRXg0UXJFbWRoQ0g0ZEJvUzYrOTBhQUZaYktNOE09
X-SES-DKIM-SIGNATURE: a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; b=TRJBPRnlVpH62kCXi8Qt/rW++rVHghq36KBh/7Jl64iV7EMQGOPCvav4ogfuQ652fU6xmhNdq4iAF3VcDWXt0KmOwZ1pf3OByx9mBlkQCOH45C4FHX2IJut5XYsyl5LyqVBVapl5JJWtkFglTBXkcIQPAeSO2ezPhG+l8ELILu8=; c=relaxed/simple; s=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono; d=amazonses.com; t=1505807261; v=1; bh=Qyte/I9jIoITAvSNOdCs6drxDrm4Bn1WsSOm2mJksBQ=; h=From:To:Cc:Bcc:Subject:Date:Message-ID:MIME-Version:Content-Type:X-SES-RECEIPT;
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono; d=amazonses.com; t=1505800214;
    h=From:To:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Message-ID:Date:Feedback-ID;
    bh=Qyte/I9jIoITAvSNOdCs6drxDrm4Bn1WsSOm2mJksBQ=;
    b=bTnigdH0nnbV+iCTInnB90ESqh/Zd2AMQSahSJvfC2HxwAiSP8kjmNj7ZGTiEmAf
    BPtzc6fwDH1MBn6wAC9DLhkv2OVSFhW0dymYDE+J0L7gZlWSEIE4xdm/ujrrZH02KAx
    TbKaSLCjkd+k97jYQKUYut/loJz5FskMt21V2M7g=
From: nelson@paralejasconsulting.com
To: lists.center@laravel.paralejas.com
Subject: FOR AMAZON TESTING
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-ID: <0100015e98afd4e4-7a7cffab-aeec-4ed9-968b-ed735a26d893-000000@email.amazonses.com>
Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2017 05:50:13 +0000
X-SES-Outgoing: 2017.09.19-54.240.8.18
Feedback-ID: 1.us-east-1.eK8pec1Sl6HG9O7rqaGwcStNFxZUYk0BWaHV30jXLsk=:AmazonSES

FOR TESTING ONLY
```

If you can notice all the values have keys except the "FOR TESTING ONLY" text below which is the message of the email, my question is how can I get that message if it does not have a key?

Comment: The message payload is separated from the Headers by a newline. Just split on that `\n\n`. Not sure what this has to do with either Python or S3.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I am using python and the text that i pasted is came from the file inside of a bucket in Amazon S3, I am sorry if my title was wrong i'm just a new both Python and AWS so i am basing my question on what i am using. Anyways thank you for your answer and will try it. Thank you

Comment: What you have posted here is the contents of an email with its headers (which you normally don't see because your email program parses them)

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Thank you for the information sir. your solution works thank you again.